# Proof for sum of squares formula

Tags: self-study, distributions, population

I'm new to the domain of statistics and i'm trying to accumulate as much info as i can right now. The problem is that from the get go most statistics books use the sum of squares for population formula : $SS= \sum{X^2} - \frac{(\sum(X))^2}{n} .$  Where can i find a proof for this formula? I've tried to prove it myself from $SS= \sum{X-m_x} $ , where $m_x$ is the mean of the population $X$ but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$SS = \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2$

$ = \sum_i [x_i^2 - 2x_i \bar{x} + \bar{x}^2  ]$

$ = \sum_i x_i^2 - 2 \bar{x} \sum_i x_i + n \bar{x}^2$

$ = \sum_i x_i^2 - 2 \bar{x} (n\bar{x})  + n \bar{x}^2$

$ = \sum_i x_i^2 - n \bar{x}^2$

replacing $\bar{x}$ with $\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}$ gets you the formula.